# Stata: Label Continuous Variable

Tags: stata

I want to create a histogram for my continuous variable x that has lots of outliers (let's say values greater than 100 and less than -100 are where the outliers are). In order to make the histogram easy to read, I aggregate the values of x greater than 100 and less than -100.

However, I also want to label the values 100 and -100 as >=100 and <=-100 respectively. However, I couldn't figure out how to label only two values of a continuous variable in Stata.

Comment: You should at least attempt code or show a data example that can be used. If you don't want to show your own data. it is usually easy to think up a question phrased in terms of a standard Stata dataset such as the auto or Grunfeld data.

Comment: You're right Nick. I'll add a sample data set and my attempted code from now on! Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 gen whatever2 = clip(whatever, -100, 100)
 label def whatever2 -100 "{&le}-100" 100 "{&ge}100" 
 label val whatever2 whatever2 
 histogram whatever2 , start(-100) width(10) xla(, valuelabel)
```

should get you started. You may need to specify which `xlabel()`s are shown.

I would just use -- or want to see -- a quantile plot for some transformed scale, such as cube root, sign(*y*) log(1 + |*y*|) or asinh(*y*). Don't hide outliers!