# Stata: esttab decimal comma

Tags: latex, export, stata

Is there a way to add decimal commas (1000 --> 1,000) on exported esttab results on Stata?

Comment: please consider this advice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66391106/stata-label-continuous-variable#comment117384116_66391106

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `format` your output, in your case by using:

`fmt(%9.Xfc)`

The `c` denotes the comma separator, the `X` is the number of decimal points you want to print.